# Is my proof for this statement correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

$$x^{ 2 }-11x+35=5\Leftrightarrow (x\in\mathbb{Z} \quad and \quad |x-5.5|<1)$$

Assume: $x^{ 2 }-11x+35=5\Rightarrow (x\in\mathbb{Z} \quad and \quad |x-5.5|<1)$

1) Then, $x^2-11x+30=0$

2) Then, $(x-5)(x-6)=0$

3) Therefore, $x=5 \quad or \quad x=6$

4) So, $x\in\mathbb{Z} \quad |x-5.5|=0.5$

5) Therefore, $x\in\mathbb{Z} \quad and \quad |x-5.5|<1$

Assume: $(x\in\mathbb{Z} \quad and \quad |x-5.5|<1)\Rightarrow x^{ 2 }-11x+35=5$

1) $-1<x-5.5 <1 \Rightarrow x^2-11x+30=0$

2) $4.5<x<6.5 \quad and \quad (x-6)(x-5)=0$

3) Therefore, $4.5<x<6.5$ in order to satisfy $(x-6)(x-5)=0$

4) Since $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $4.5<x<6.5$ and $(x-6)(x-5)=0$, $x=6, x=5$

5) Therefore $x^2-11x+35=5$

Is my proof flawed in any way? If so, what can I do to fix it? If it isn't flawed, how can I improve it?

Comment: The statement itself is flawed: For $x=5$ we have "$x\in\Bbb Z$ and $|x-5.5|<1$", but $x^2-11x+35=5\ne 0$.

Comment: Whoops, that's embarrassing. That was a typo. Sorry.

Comment: I would suggest starting part 1 with the header: *Proof ($\implies$):* followed by the assumption of the Lhs of the statement, and part 2 with the header *Proof ($\impliedby$):*. Also be a bit more explicit in part 2 that $|x-5.5|^2<1 \implies x^2-11x+30.25<1 \implies x^2-11x+30=0$ because $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Just a question of style. Both times you say: "Assume...", you should replace the "Assume" by "Assuming" and  $\Rightarrow$ by "I will show that...". The way you wrote it, it seems that you are assuming the whole sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that in the second half you're working both forwards and backwards - you're starting with the $|x−5.5|<1$ requirement and also working backwards from the end goal of $x^2−11x+35=5$. It looks like in line one you're assuming the implication ("Assume: $(x∈Z$ $and$ $|x−5.5|<1)⇒x^2−11x+35=5$") and then using that to prove itself. Notice how it's different than in the first half, where you only worked with the statement you assumed.

Basically you want to drop everything after "and" in lines one and two of the second half (the polynomial stuff). This leads to some issues on lines 3 and 4. However, it's not a proof-breaking issue. What I would change it to is something like this:

3) We know from (2) that $4.5 < x < 6.5$, so since $x∈Z$ we have $x = 5$ $or$ $6$.

4) Taking these values of $x$ as the zeroes of a second order polynomial, we have $(x-6)(x-5)=0$.

5) Expanding, we have $x^2−11x+30=0$ $⇒$ $x^2−11x+35=5$. QED

Comment: This is what I did to improve the second part of my proof:

Assuming: $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, I will show that $x^2-11x+35=5$

1) $-1<x-5.5<1$

2) Then, $4.5<x<6.5$ and $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, so $x=5$ or $x=6$

3) Taking these values of x as solutions to a second degree polynomial, we have : $(x-6)(x-5)=0$

4) By expanding $(x-6)(x-5)=0$, we get $x^2-11x+30=0$, which can also be written as: $x^2-11x+35=5$

QED

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, to prove this result we can prove each direction separately.

Lets start with proving $x^2−11x+35=5⇒x \in \{n∈ \mathbb{Z} : |n−5.5|<1\}$.

Assume: $x^2−11x+35=5$

- Notice that I don't assume $x^2−11x+35=5⇒x \in \{n∈ \mathbb{Z} : |n−5.5|<1\}$ since if I did then I would already have the result.

The rest of your proof for this direction is good. Finding the values of $x$ that make $x^2−11x+35=5$ true and checking if those values are in the set $\{n∈ \mathbb{Z} : |n−5.5|<1\}$.

Now to prove $x \in \{n∈ \mathbb{Z} : |n−5.5|<1\}⇒x^2−11x+35=5$.

Assume: $x \in \{n∈ \mathbb{Z} : |n−5.5|<1\}$

From here since $\{n∈ \mathbb{Z} : |n−5.5|<1\}$ has only two elements to prove the required result I would just plug both elements into $ x^2−11x+35=5 $ to see if the result is true.